# Can a small amount of scandium be added to gold, platinum or palladium to create a wedding ring?

Tags: alloy

The number 21 has a special meaning to us, so we would like to make wedding rings with some scandium in it (element 21). I know scandium can be alloyed with aluminium or titanium, but can it also be alloyed with say gold, platinum or palladium without detrimental effects?

Comment: Sc would seem to alloy with Au. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925838897000224 Where to get the Sc and how to get the alloy made, then the alloy into ring(s) are different problems.

Comment: A careful elementar analysis will probably find the odd scandium atom in a plain wedding ring. Perhaps the printout of the spectrograph will be enough? Will likely be cheaper than finding s.o. who makes you the alloy and forges a ring later.

Comment: Coincidentally you now have 21 rep. Congratulations.

Comment: Planning to get married?

Answer (score 19):

The go-to place for alloy information is [ASM International's Alloy Phase Diagram Database](http://mio.asminternational.org/apd/index.aspx) (providing your institution has access).

Scandium-Gold: as noted in the comment by @MaxW, you can get several atomic percent (but less than 10 at.%) Sc in Au. There exist 6 compounds across the diagram which you would want to avoid most likely.

Scandium-Platinum: likely up to about 10 at.% of Sc in Pt. At least several compounds to avoid.

Scandium-Palladium: also order of 10 at.% of Sc. 5 compounds to avoid.

All the compounds should be avoided because (1) they are higher in scandium content, and (2) they are mostly line compounds and unlikely to be malleable.

So, yes, you can get scandium in to a gold-platinum-palladium mix. Find a good jeweler and they can melt it in for you. Scandium is not all that expensive (at least compared to the cost of getting the jeweler to do a custom alloy).